# Should maven project created with Java 8 work with newer Java releases?

Tags: java, maven-3

I created a maven project that worked with Java 8 and tested with Java 8 (pom specified 1.8).

To run this project in a machine with newer java (like Java 9) installed, I wonder shall the project run with newer java automatically since newer java is supposed to be backward compatible?

In general, I wonder what needs to be done to make a maven project work with newer Java releases.

Comment: Usually nothing. The exception would be if you have used a new reserved word (like `var`) in your source; when you recompile it there may be some changes needed under new versions. If you don't recompile, then it should continue to work (for the foreseeable future).

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is backward compatible. Maven plugins like compiler is not.
You need to do something as below [for java 11]:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>
<configuration>
    <release>11</release>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

And also generally speaking you should be updating your dependencies to its respective latest version.
Please check the details in [this article](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/)

Again, it would help if you mention a specific problem after you start running your old project as this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398894/unable-to-compile-simple-java-10-java-11-project-with-maven)

For java 9, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583118/is-maven-ready-for-jdk9)